# Docker-compose doesn't expose PORTS so cannot access localhost

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

So I successfully created docker container which works like a charm. Created just a basic to test it.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18.7.0

WORKDIR /

COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["bin/bash"]
```

When starting the container like this: `docker run -it -p 5555:5555 container` I can easily access the server with the help of Postman.

However, when I create docker-compose, the Postman doesn't see that the server is up and running. Even `docker ps` shows blank on `PORTS` section whereas docker-container shows `0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp`

[image: Docker-container]
[image: Docker-compose]

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  weatherly-server:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./
    working_dir: /
    command: npm start
    ports: 
     - "5555:5555"
```

It starts perfectly, the server is listening on port 5555. Just that I cannot access the server.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you go inside the container using exec is it accessible using curl?

Comment: You container CMD differs from the command-statement in your compose file.  

My assumption is, the the container ends/crashes immediately with your compose file.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen Nope, it not crashes. Even deleted command from docker-compose ant left only on docker container - same issue.

Comment: @RazLuvaton indeed.

Comment: What URL are you using in Postman to access your service and what is the failure message?

Comment: @ChristophDahlen I am accessing http://localhost:5555/place/.... . Well the error states about the connection err. However, I see that the server is running and listening on "port 5555"

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is related to Docker for Mac, but `docker-compose run weatherly-server`does not forward ports whereas `docker-compose up weahterly-server`does.